# Is this sentence acceptable?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I one wrote a sentence:

> It is hard to wipe away the impression of a boy has left, especially the one who is in his twenties and is usually alone without the presence of his parents though already grown up.

In this sentence, I want to convey some information:

1.the boy is 23 years old , is ' in his twenties' proper?

2.the boy doesn't t have much time to live with his parents?
3.Is the whole sentence understandable?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not correct.  It should read as follows:

"It is hard to wipe away the impression of a boy **who** has **moved out of his parents' house**, especially the one who is in his twenties and is usually alone without the presence of his parents though already grown up."

First, you need to put the relative pronoun "who" between "boy" and "has" to open up a relative clause like the one you are trying to do.  Second, when you just say "a boy who has left", it comes off at first that he has just gone out for the night and he'll be back.  If you want to convey that he's moved out of his parents' house, you have to make that clear.  If I said,

"The boy has left,"

it means he's gone for the time being, but he will be back.  If you want to convey that the boy won't be returning, you should say,

"The boy has moved out of his parents' house,"

or

"The boy has left for good."

The statements I am showing you are independent clauses, which are just normal statements made.  Yours is a relative clause, so I've already shown you that you have to insert a "who" between "boy" and "has".  The above examples are to show you what I think you are trying to say.  Third, if you want to say the boy is 23-years-old, then describing him as "one who is in his twenties" does not do the job; you would have to say "one who is twenty-three".

I hope that might have helped you out.  Take care and good luck.